# How to create RDLC report from dynamic query in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-express

I can't create the rdlc report from this procedure, I'm using report viewer but when I select the procedure, it doesn't show any column names but my procedure returns 7 columns. How can I create the report please help ? I'm creating the report in vb.net

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Pr_getAcceptedOnDateReport
@date date
AS
SET FMTONLY OFF
DECLARE  @SQL varchar(MAX)
DECLARE  @antiHIV bit
DECLARE  @HBsAg bit
DECLARE  @IGMHBCore bit
DECLARE  @NAT bit
DECLARE  @Malaria bit
DECLARE  @TotalHBCore bit
DECLARE  @Syphilis bit
DECLARE  @HCV bit
DECLARE  @ICT bit
DECLARE  @DCT bit
DECLARE  @Antibody bit

 Select @antiHIV=[HIV1/2 screen Reactive],
@IGMHBCore=[IgM HBcore Reactive], 
@HBsAg=[HBsAg Screen Reactive],
@NAT= [NAT Reactive],
@Malaria=[Malaria Screen Reactive],
@TotalHBCore=[Total HBcore Reactive],
@Syphilis=[Syphilis Screen Reactive],
@HCV=[HCV screen Reactive],
@ICT=[ICT Positive],
@DCT= [DCT Positive],
@Antibody= [Antibody Screen Positive]
 from m_rejectionRules where deleted=0

 DECLARE @sql1 nvarchar(4000)    

 Select @sql1='Select t.donorid, t.donorname, t.sampleid, t.customid,t.bagtype,t.bagnumber, t.segmentno from ttidetail t, m_donor m 
where t.donorid=m.donorid 
AND  CONVERT(date, m.RDate) =''' + cast(@date as varchar(100)) + ''''

IF @antiHIV='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.antiHIV like ' + ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END
IF @HBsAg='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.HBsAg like '+ ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END
IF @IGMHBCore='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.IGM_antiHBC like '+ ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END
IF @NAT='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.NAT_HIV1 like '+ ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END
IF @Malaria='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.malariaScreen like '+ ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END
IF @TotalHBCore='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.totalAnti_HBC like '+ ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END

IF @Syphilis='True' 
BEGIN
SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + ' AND t.SyphilisScreen like '+ ''''+ 'Non%Reactive'+''''
END


EXEC sp_executesql @sql1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which maps to your fields returned by your stored procedure

```
Public Class ReportData

Property donorid AS Integer = 0
Property donorname as string = string.empty
Property sampleid as integer = 0 
Property customid as integer = 0
Property bagtype as string = string.empty
Property bagnumber as integer = 0
Property segmentno as integer = 0

End Class
```

Assuming that you have a function which returns a dataset using the above query, I will refer to it as ds

*** MOST IMPORTANT *** 
When creating your rdlc report instead of mapping to the storedprocdure map it to an object datasource and select the class you just created. Use the fileds in this class as fields for your report.

In the button show report you can use the following code to display your report

```
Private Sub ShowReport()
    Dim dsL As DataSet = New DataSet()
    dsL = GetReportData()  ' Function which will get the data from the SQL Query

    Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource()
    rds.Name = "ReportDS" ' Change to what you will be using when creating an objectdatasource
    rds.Value = dsL.Tables(0)
    With rvReport   ' Name of the report control on the form
        .Reset()
        .ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
        .LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        .Visible = True
        .LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath
        .LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)


        ' If you have any parameters you can pass them here
        Dim rptParameters As New List(Of ReportParameter)()
        With rptParameters
            .Add(New ReportParameter("Title",
                String.Format("{0} Grid For Period {1} To {2}",
                    gridType,
                    FormatDateTime(startDate, DateFormat.ShortDate),
                    FormatDateTime(endDate, DateFormat.ShortDate))))
            .Add(New ReportParameter("SubTitle", String.Format("Program: {0}", ucProgram.Text)))
            .Add(New ReportParameter("StartDate", startDate))
            .Add(New ReportParameter("EndDate", endDate))
        End With
        .LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParameters)

        .RefreshReport()
    End With

End Sub
```